# Linear Regression Restricted minimization

Tags: regression

> Consider independent observations ${(y_i, x_{1i}, x_{2i}) : 1 ≤ i ≤ n}$ from the regression model $y_i = β_1x_{1i} + β_2x_{2i} + e_i, i = 1, . . . , n$ ,where $x_{1i}$ and $x_{2i}$ are scalar covariates, $β_1$ and $β_2$ are unknown scalar coefficients, and $e_i$ are uncorrelated errors with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2 > 0$. Instead of using the correct model, we obtain an estimate $\hat{β_1} $ of $β_1$ by minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i -\beta_1X_{1i})^2$.Find the bias and mean squared error of $\hat{β_1} $.

By minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^n (Y_i -\beta_1X_{1i})^2$ I found that $\hat{β_1}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_{1i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i}^2}$. Now, Bias of $\hat{β_1}$ is $E(\hat{β_1})-\beta_1$. I'm not sure how to find $E(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_ix_{1i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i}^2})$. Can someone please suggest any reading material to learn how to find this or provide hints?